# How do you create an object from points, in order to be able to insert it into a GUI?

Tags: html, three.js, 3d, frontend

I am currently following Bruno Simons Three.js journey, in the section regarding Mixing Html with WebGl, in the tutorial you are essentially trying to pin a text box to a 3D model.
I have the GUI imported and ready but I'm finding it hard to understand what it is I need to 'gui.add(...)' to be able to tweak the position of the text in the GUI.

**HTML**

```
<div class="point point-0">
 <div class="label">1</div>
 <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
     adipisicing elit. Neque commodi consequatur maxime.
     </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
  const points = [
{
    position: new THREE.Vector3(1.55, 0.1,  1.9),
    element: document.querySelector('.point-0')
}
```

]

**in the tick function**

```
for(const point of points)
 {
 const screenPosition = point.position.clone()
 screenPosition.project(camera)
 const translateX = screenPosition.x * sizes.width * 0.5
 const translateY = - screenPosition.y * sizes.height * 0.5
 point.element.style.transform = `translate(${translateX}px, ${translateY}px)`}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer for anyone else who has this problem is that the GUI must be added with the index after the object:

```
`gui.add(points[0].position, 'y')`
```

which is the `'[0]'` after the '`points`'

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these examples on Particle Systems using points:

[Points Billboards](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=points#webgl_points_billboards)

[Interactive Points](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=points#webgl_interactive_points)

Instead of using points, you can map an image to the point. Take a look at [this](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Particle-Engine.html) amazing particle system for effects, which actually maps an image of the effect if you see the code.

So, to recap, you would want to map an image to your point(s). [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201024024600/https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/) is a great tutorial to get you started.

Good luck!

Comment: I think this is the way thank you very much you have saved my life!!!

Comment: Of course! Happy to help :)